# Jordan-Holder theorem for group algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, representation-theory, algebras

I'm currently studying the Jordan-Holder theorem for modules and representations of associative algebras over fields. I was wondering if there is a way to prove the Jordan-Holder theorem for finite groups using the Jordan-Holder theorem in the case of group algebras. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, due to non-commutativity of groups and the fact that every module has an underlying *abelian* group. That's not a strict proof of impossibility, but it seems unlikely.

However, there is a way to prove a version of Jordan-Hölder that covers finite groups, finite length modules over a ring (and more!): you need to introduce [groups with operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_with_operators), which simultaneously generalize groups and modules over a ring. IIRC, Jacobson treats this in Basic Algebra I.

Comment: It's also in Aschbacher, "Finite Group Theory" and Robinson, "A course in the theory of groups"

Comment: This treatment of groups with operators is something I think of as a prominent feature in Martin Isaacs _Algebra: a graduate course_!  It definitely has this version of Jordan-Hölder.